# The usage of Porch vs. Patio

Tags: dialects

I'm a student originally from the West Coast but currently studying in New England. I came across an interesting question concerning dialectology and the use of Patio vs. Porch. I have observed other words like Deck, Veranda, Lanai... etc. Where can I find evidence to show that this is a regional difference or just preference? Thanks!

Comment: Hi M. Munoz, I find your question terribly unclear. Does your understanding of *patio* or *porch*, or the understanding you found in New England, diverge from the definitions you find in dictionaries? You should share that with us, so that we’re able to understand what the question is.

Comment: Don't forget to add 'stoop' to the regional mix. In any case I'd say that while some of those terms are regionalisms, some of them are distinct things. A patio (veranda, lanai) is not the same as a deck, which is different from a porch (stoop) or a balcony.

Comment: *porch* and *patio* are different in my book.  Do a Google image search for both to get a feel for the difference.

Comment: The gist of the question seems to be "where can I find evidence". So this is a request for reputable sources that would help.

Comment: @Jim: A *porch* is a *stoop*? Not in my book. Maybe all stoops are porches, but not all porches are stoops.

Comment: @PeterShor - Did I say anything about *stoops*? Oh, other Jim...

Comment: @PeterShor  Yeah, *porch* and *stoop* aren't direct substitutes. A *stoop* is a particular case of the broader *porch*. Again, it's a regionalism so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

This is more under the purview of architectural and building nomenclature as far as distinction is concerned. Here you are:
http://www.homedit.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-porch-balcony-verandapatio-and-deck/

Keep in mind that the regional differences in word usage can often be on account of varying climates. For instance, New Englanders experience many types of inclement weather, and often have porches which are covered, so that they can be enjoyed for most of the year. On the other hand, people in Nevada often have patios as it is most often sunny, and there is no need for a covering. Respectively, a region will usually generalize to the most common structure, and so New Englanders (I am one myself) will often use porch for veranda or even sometimes deck.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

UK usage ...

'Porch' - an exterior structure forming a covered approach to the entrance of a building (at least partially protected from the weather). (OED)

'Patio' - a paved roofless area adjoining and belonging to a house; esp. a garden terrace (where tables,chairs, BBQs can be put). (OED)

Comment: Quite right. The only thing I would add is that *patio*, in Britain is a relatively recent addition to the language, and not a traditional term. A borrowing from Spanish it was used in America long before we got in on the act. A *verandah* (from Hindi) is one of those colonial words introduced into English. A *verandah* is an open space that extends along the front of a dwelling and offers shade, and shelter. Verandahs are less common in Britain itself  than they were among the British in India. Australian houses are big on *verandahs*. I think Americans call them something else.

Comment: In (western) US usage, a porch would be elevated above ground level and probably built (mostly) of wood.  A patio would be close to ground level, and probably floored with concrete, stone, or similar.  It might or might not be roofed, or even enclosed.  (Mine has removable panels, so closed in winter, open in warmer months.)